# conditional string with ternary operator not working on multi language string - javascript nodejs

Tags: javascript, string, unicode

### Desired result:

if variable `cityName` present -------------> " :أوقات الصلاة في كراتشي"

if variable `cityName` is not present -----> " :أوقات الصلاة"

---

### what I am getting:

`${(cityName) ? " :" + cityName + "في "  : ":"}وقت الصلاة\n`

> " :karachiفي وقت الصلاة↵"

`وقت الصلاة${(cityName) ? (" :" +cityName+" في ") : (":")}\n`;

> "وقت الصلاة :karachi في ↵"

may be this is the problem with arabic language because even I remove the english latters just for testing it doesnt work:

`وقت الصلاة${(cityName) ? (" :في كراتشي") : (":")}\n`;

> "وقت الصلاة :في كراتشي↵"

`${(cityName) ? (" :في كراتشي") : (":")} وقت الصلاة\n`;

> " :في كراتشي وقت الصلاة↵"

no matter What I do I never get correct result, what I am looking for is how do I get correct result according to my need, in addition if anyone can tell me what is the science of multilanguage (of different starting sides such as english from left and arabic from right) in string  would be thankful .
I am using this approach in english from years it works fine but with arabic it is not working

Answer (score 1):

The best fix for this when displaying Arabic text that has a non-Arabic character at the end is to include the Unicode RTL code after the non-Arabic character.

This happens when placing Neutral Characters such as punctuation between different directional text runs. For example, the Arabic Unicode Table does not have the equivalent codes for the characters ! @ # $ % * : &

When you add any of these Latin characters to the end of Arabic text, that character positions itself correctly to the right of the Arabic text (i.e. before the Arabic text reading from right to left); this is incorrect according to the direction of the Arabic text.

By adding the Unicode for RTL "\u200F" after the Neutral Latin Char; you instruct that the Latin char maintains RTL as the remaining text; this will fix the problem. This works irrespective of the original direction of the sentence be it RTL or LTR because the Arabic characters always take the RTL direction.

This also allows combining RTL and LTR text in the same sentence.

Here is an example to (I hope) will fix this for you:

Of course, this only to give you an idea. Forget about how I am concatenating the strings; it is only for explanation.

**You can adapt it for the ternary operator easily.**

```js
function showPrayerTime(city,Time) {
  let RTL = "\u200F";
  let prefix = "أوقات الصلاة";
  let prefix2 = prefix + " " + "في" + " ";
  
  switch (city) {
     
    case "KHI" :
      result = prefix2 + "كراتشي" + ":" + RTL;
      break;
      //---------------------
      case "DOH" :
      result = prefix2 + "الدوحة" + ":" + RTL;
      break;
      //---------------------
    default:
     result = prefix + ":" + RTL;
      
  }
  
  return result
  
}

console.log(showPrayerTime("KHI"));
console.log(showPrayerTime("DOH"));
console.log(showPrayerTime(""));
```

You can read more about it the RTL Unicode here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html

**And using the Ternary Operator example:**

```js
let cityName = "كراتشي";
let prefix = "وقت الصلاة";
let suffix = ":" + "\u200F";


//==== example 1
let result = cityName ? prefix+" في "+cityName+suffix : prefix+suffix;
console.log(result)


//==== example 2
cityName = "";
result = cityName ? prefix+" في "+cityName+suffix : prefix+suffix;
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your first line says ${(cityName) ? " :" + cityName + "في " : ":"}وقت الصلاة\n this is saying that if cityName, then return everything between ? And : (without the quotes), not sure why you're adding ":" plus the city name again.

This is not an issue with Unicode letters, it's just the format.

Let's take an example with English letters. If cityname, return "new York", if not, return "nothing", so

`${cityName ? "new York" : "nothing"}`

But I'm guessing you want to return the actual value of city name somehow, but I can't read Arabic nor do I know where the original cityName variable was defined, do I can't help you there, but the format of the inline if statements is the condition, followed by a ?, Followed by the resulting expression that is returned if condition is met, followed by :, followed by expression that is returned if not

Comment: with only english letters it is working perfectly fine, I am using this approach from years, but today when I did this in arabic it is behaving weird

Comment: I am adding plus because what I am returning is not a simple string, instead it is a combination of simple string and string variable

Comment: @inz k so what is the option. Did you first try it with simple strings?